# How can I load form options from Doctrine entity (Symfony 4)?

Tags: symfony, oop, entity, formbuilder

I am trying to load my formbuilder options from my Doctrine entity `FieldTypes`:

```
$formBuilder->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
          'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2'), 'label' => 'Type',
          'class' => FieldTypes::class,
        ));
```

But I get the error message:

> Class App\Controller\FieldTypes does not exist

Comment: What is the full name of `FieldTypes` class?

Comment: pls show your `namespaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put a use at the top of class:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\FieldTypes;

class MyController
{
    // ...

    public function myAction()
    {
        // ...

        $formBuilder->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control select2'
            ),
            'label' => 'Type',
            'class' => FieldTypes::class,
        ));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```